# Single & multi sensor code

Tags: arduino-uno

I have been having problems trying to run multi sensor code for my project, this requires four KY-024 Linear magnetic Hall sensors as position sensors that trigger NC independent relays to make a circuit.
I can get the code to run on one independent circuit, one hall switch one relay with no problems.
But when I try the code for 4 hall sensors + relays I get no response from the circuit at this point I am at a loss where to go from here the code compiled with no problems.

```
int hallswitch = 1;
int val = 0;
int RELAY1 = 6;

void setup() {
  pinMode(hallswitch, INPUT);
  pinMode(RELAY1, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  val = digitalRead(hallswitch);

  if (val == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(RELAY1, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(RELAY1, LOW);
  }
}
```

and

```
int hallswitch1 = 1;  //Pin for Hall switch
int hallswitch2 = 2;  //Pin for Hall switch
int hallswitch3 = 4;  //Pin for Hall switch
int hallswitch4 = 5;  //Pin for Hall switch

int val = 0;       //Integer for reading Hall statu

int RELAY1 = 6;    // The socket number on the Arduino that the relay1 will go to.
int RELAY2 = 7;    // The socket number on the Arduino that the relay1 will go to.
int RELAY3 = 8;    // The socket number on the Arduino that the relay1 will go to.
int RELAY4 = 9;    // The socket number on the Arduino that the relay1 will go to.

void setup()
{
  pinMode(hallswitch1, INPUT);
  pinMode (RELAY1, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(hallswitch2, INPUT);
  pinMode (RELAY2, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(hallswitch3, INPUT);
  pinMode (RELAY3, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(hallswitch4, INPUT);
  pinMode (RELAY4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  val = digitalRead(hallswitch1);               //Read Hall pin status
  val = digitalRead(hallswitch2);               //Read Hall pin status
  val = digitalRead(hallswitch3);               //Read Hall pin status
  val = digitalRead(hallswitch4);               //Read Hall pin status

  if (val == HIGH) {                        //If there is a magnet infront of Hall switch...
    digitalWrite(RELAY1, HIGH);             // Turn RELAY1 on:
    digitalWrite(RELAY2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RELAY3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RELAY4, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(RELAY1, LOW);               // Turn RELAY1 off:
    digitalWrite(RELAY2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RELAY3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RELAY4, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are writing all four sensors to the save variable 'val'    Although that will not stop the code from running, but it means the only one you are actually doing anything with is hallswitch4, and you using that value to turn on or off all of the relays,

Comment: What do you mean 'get no response'? If you are only trying switches 1,2, or 3 you will not get any response as their values are being over written.

Comment: how could i get the code to run 4 hall sensors independently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the quick and dirty way, I would suggest re writing it to use arrays rather then having to declare all these variables and copy paste pinMode, read,writes if statments a bunch of times.

```
 int hallswitch1 = 1;  //Pin for Hall switch
 int hallswitch2 = 2;  //Pin for Hall switch
 int hallswitch3 = 4;  //Pin for Hall switch 
 int hallswitch4 = 5;  //Pin for Hall switch

 int val1 = 0;       //Integer for reading Hall statu  
 int val2 = 0; 
 int val3 = 0;
 int val4 = 0;

 int RELAY1 = 6;    // The socket number on the Arduino that the relay1 will go to.
 int RELAY2 = 7;    // The socket number on the Arduino that the relay1 will go to.
 int RELAY3 = 8;    // The socket number on the Arduino that the relay1 will go to.
 int RELAY4 = 9;    // The socket number on the Arduino that the relay1 will go to.

void setup()
{

  pinMode(hallswitch1, INPUT); 
  pinMode (RELAY1, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(hallswitch2, INPUT);
  pinMode (RELAY2, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(hallswitch3, INPUT);
  pinMode (RELAY3, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(hallswitch4, INPUT);
  pinMode (RELAY4, OUTPUT);  

}

void loop() {

  val1 = digitalRead(hallswitch1);               //Read Hall pin status
  val2 = digitalRead(hallswitch2);               //Read Hall pin status
  val3 = digitalRead(hallswitch3);               //Read Hall pin status
  val4 = digitalRead(hallswitch4);               //Read Hall pin status



  if (val1 == HIGH) {digitalWrite(RELAY1, HIGH);}
  else {digitalWrite(RELAY1, LOW);}

  if (val2 == HIGH) {digitalWrite(RELAY2, HIGH);}
  else {digitalWrite(RELAY2, LOW);}

  if (val3 == HIGH) {digitalWrite(RELAY3, HIGH);}
  else {digitalWrite(RELAY3, LOW);}

  if (val4 == HIGH) {digitalWrite(RELAY4, HIGH);}
  else {digitalWrite(RELAY4, LOW);}

}
```

Comment: also all of the 'pin' variables RELAYx and hallswitchx dont need to be variables since you are not changing them, they are constants.   use #define RELAY1 6     ect

Comment: Chad thank you for your help the code works as intended